# Alternative to transfer files via command line (not using SSH)

Tags: command-line, networking, server, ssh, vpn

Because of my job I need to connect to a remote server with SSH on which I am connected by vpn and transfer large files in both directions. That has always been easy until I traveled to another continent where I am now, in which I am getting very high ping and very low transfer speed.
I thought that it would be much faster simply uploading my filed to the internet and downloading them on the server (and vice-versa) to avoid the slow ssh connection. It would be great to do it by command line. I know how to download files via command line but not how to upload. Does anyone know a good alternative?

Comment: When you say you’re copying files via SSH, are you using `scp`? 

Comment: @matigo, actually i was using sshfs but that became impossible now.

Comment: Ah yes, but I tried scp too. I still have the same problem. When I was in the same city as the remote server both options scp and sshfs were good, but now they are too slow.

Comment: Okay … so you’re not looking for a tool, you’re looking for speed. If this is the case, your bottleneck is going to be the slowest connection between you and the target, which isn’t something software is going to fix 

Comment: Yes that is it. The difference is so big that it is faster to upload the file somwhere else (like Google drive) and later download it again. The point is that I dont know any way to upload a file by command line. So I wonder if there is a way to do that

Comment: How many people use the remote server? If the answer is "one", then perhaps a Google Drive Sync or Dropbox Sync mechanism would work better ...

Comment: Ah it is used by the whole company.. I am not allowed to install directly on the server. But I could try to run a docker container and run the Google drive sync from there maybe? I have no idea if it is possible

Comment: I don't see how "file exchange using the command line" will improve your upload/download speed. Should make that clear in the Question above, lest folks think it's an [XY question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Just a thought, one thing that may help, (and it is easy enough to check beforehand whether or not it is needed, or if it will make a difference at all, with a smart phone app) is the broadband channel. In my experience, many users will either not know about the option, or else opt not to bother with this. There are 16 channels that make up your broadband, and only 2-3 that are used regularly in default configurations from most ISPs. Usuallly channels 1 & 2, along with one of the middle ones.. cant remember the number.

Comment: Anyway, you can get software to check the availability of all channels in your area. I use a smart phone app, but I am sure there are a number of great apt solutions as well. That said, this is one case where viewing the results graph  a GUI makes the process a lot quicker / easier. If you have a lot of users, as you say, and they are all on one interface / one channel, reconfiguring may be worth considering.

Comment: you do compress the files?

Answer (score -1):

There is FTP which doesn't use ssh. That said, is relatively unsafe. The safe version of FTP is SFTP, which uses...  yup, SSH over FTP (likely the very protocol that provoked this question.)

There is also telnet, bet that is just a plain bad idea. With telnet you are putting yourself out there, literally.

All these use TCP, which involves 3way handshake authentication. Using UDP skips this and is generally faster, but for small files.

As Matigo said, there is no fix for physical distance. There are improvements that you could make, but they will likely end up being little more than band-aids on a gunshot wound.